# Lost Focus Events for a Control Within GridView

Tags: asp.net, events, gridview

I have multiple textboxes and dropdown lists within my GridView. For one particular textbox I need trigger a server event which gets data from the database and fills it in other columns of the Grid. Is there a simple way to do it or a slightly complicated way as detailed [here](http://sbiefeld.com/2008/09/extending-the-aspnet-textbox-to-have-an-onblur-server-side-event/)

I have no problems implementing the above method or thinking of a work around but then thought that there is Cell Lost Focus in a grid control surprises me a little. Am I missing something ? Any help on this would appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `AutoPostBack` to true and handle it's `TextChanged` event.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  EmptyDataText="It's Empty.">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" 
                             runat="server" 
                             Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>' 
                             AutoPostBack="true"
                             OnTextChanged="NameChanged" >
                </asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
     </Columns>
</GridView>
```

in codebehind:

```
protected void NameChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var txtName = (TextBox) sender;
    var row = (GridViewRow) txtName.NamingContainer;
    // you could find other controls in this GridViewRow via 
    // row.FindControl("ControlID") in case of a TemplateField or
    // row.Cells[0].Text (0 = index of column) in case of a BoundField
}
```